# In Kotlin, Which type can accept values of both integers and decimal numbers?

Tags: kotlin

Int - Only accepts numbers without decimals.
Double - Accepts integers but format should be like 40.0 instead of just using 40.

I tried using Double , But it is not working.

So which type should i be using if i want to be able to work with both with plain integers and also decimals? Is there a type

heres some simple code that adds two numbers that tries to illustrate my problem.

```
fun main() {
fun sumOf(x:Double, y:Double) : Double{
    return (x+y)
}
val result=  sumOf(40,41.5)
print(result)} //error
```

Comment: `Number`, just like in Java

Comment: "I tried using Double , But it is not working." Can you show a [mcve] and show what exactly is not working?

Comment: It would be cool  Instead of having to type 40.0 in a double in the code above to fix error , i was wondering if there was a type which can just accept 40 and also 41.5 as well.

Comment: @rakeshs: Nothing you can do math with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a bit of confusion here about the different types in Kotlin, and how you express them as literals in code.

```
val anInt = 3
val aLong = 3L
val aFloat = 3f // or 3.0f if you like, the f is what makes it a float
val aDouble = 3.0
```

In the above code, `anInt`'s type is inferred to be `Int`, because *you're assigning an `Int` to it*. A sequence of digits without a decimal point is an integer literal, and will produce an `Int` unless you add the `L` mark to make it a `Long` instead. (You'll also get a `Long` without the mark if the value is so large it requires a `Long` to represent it, but that's not an issue here.)

Similarly, a number *with a decimal point* (but without the `f` suffix) *is a `Double`*. That's how you write them. It's not just a case of style, expressing a number in that format creates a value with a `Double` type.

So if you have a function that takes a `Double`, **you can't pass `40` to it because that's an `Int`**. You need to write it as `40.0` **because that's the `Double` representation of that number**.

---

So in your code, if you're working with `Double`s, you need to write them with the decimal point. That's just how the language works. And that shouldn't be a problem, because you're the one writing the code - you just make sure that all your number literals (i.e. numbers you're explicitly writing out) conform to the correct format. The linter/compiler will make sure you're expressing and using the correct types (which is why you're getting your error trying to pass `40` to something expecting a `Double`).

If you're working with external input, something you read in from outside at runtime, then you're probably looking at parsing strings. In which case, `"40".toDouble()` works just fine, and gives you a `Double` representation that you can use internally, pass to your functions etc. Displaying that as `"40"` again instead of `"40.0"` is more complex and really depends on your situation - but that's not what this question is about!

Answer (score 1):

Think about the conditions or use case in which you are using two different types. It might be a flawed design to use two arguments of different types in such manner.

Kotlin is strict with types and has no common interface for operators to use as a generic. This aids in creating an more expected behaviour.
Numeric values have a common interface called **Number**, this can be used to convert values between types and then you can apply the + operator.

For example:

```kotlin
fun sumOf(x: Number, y: Number): Double {
    return x.toDouble() + y.toDouble()
}
```

On the other hand you could use a different approach, which is seen in many places in the kotlin standard library. Look up the sources for min/max functions for example and use it as a reference.

```kotlin
fun sumOf(x: Double, y: Double): Double {
    return x + y
}
fun sumOf(x: Int, y: Int): Int {
    return x + y
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can’t be imprecise and use an Int (where the literal is specified as `42` with no decimal) as a Double. Kotlin strictly enforces the type of numbers you’re using to prevent possible bugs from accidentally using the wrong type of number. Integers and decimal numbers are represented differently in binary in memory, and math is calculated differently for them on the CPU, so it is important to be precise about which type of number you’re using.

Java doesn’t have this restriction, but this is considered to be a common source of bugs and therefore the Kotlin designers decided to be more strict about it.